# $wpdb->wp_users returning empty value for

Tags: php, functions, mysql

I have a code Example:

```
function custom_func(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->flush();     //tried with and without this line
    $getTest = 'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users LIMIT 1';
    $arrayReturned = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($getTest));
}
```

From what I've read I thought that $wpdb->wp_users is meant to have returned the database name and table name like so dbName.tableName; but it just returns an empty value.

I've tried:

```
$getTest = 'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users LIMIT 1';
```

which shows as the following to wordpress:

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_users LIMIT 1
```

and

```
$getTest = 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->wp_users.' LIMIT 1';
```

which shows as the following to wordpress:

```
SELECT * FROM  LIMIT 1
```

I can't fathom why this isn't working since this is all based on literature from the wordpress codex, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why you would need custom query for this basic functionality to get users, when WordPress has inbuilt function **[get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)**.

Anyway for custom query, table name is defined as

```
function custom_func(){
 global $wpdb;
 $getTest = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users LIMIT 1";
 $arrayReturned = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($getTest));
}
```

It's **$wpdb->users** or **$wpdb->post** and not **$wpdb->wp_users**, what you use for a table name, in [custom queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable).

Also I've used the double quotes **" "** for query and not single quotes **' '**, you can read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: This was just a test example based on what I was reading, but you fixed all of the problems I was having with the table name changes, thanks.

Comment: Hope you could commit to community too :)